# jquery check if input text empty is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery code

```
if (($("#RdbDateRange").is(':checked'))
        && (!$("#CldrFrom").val())
        && (!$("#CldrTo").val())) {}else{}
```

`RdbDateRange` is ID for radio button.
`CldrFrom` is ID for input text
`CldrTo` is ID for input text.

I want to do something when the radio is selected **and** both of the inputs not empty.

but that code go inside the **if** even when the inputs empty.

why please?

Comment: Empty strings are definitely `false` in a boolean context. Try applying `$.trim()` to filter out whitespace. Note that you do *not* have to explicitly test against the empty string or use `length`, as all the answers you received so far would like you to believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **.length** property, For spaces You can use [**$.trim()**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

```
if ($("#RdbDateRange").is(':checked')
    && $.trim($("#CldrFrom").val()).length
    && $.trim($("#CldrTo").val()).length){}else{}
```

OR,

You can also use [**.trim()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim), Note: this function is supported in IE9+

```
if ($("#RdbDateRange").is(':checked')
    && $("#CldrFrom").val().trim().length
    && $("#CldrTo").val().trim().length){}else{}
```

### EDIT

As per requirement `the radio is selected and both of the inputs not empty`

You don't need `!`, thus remove it

Comment: maybe the input has spaces, just spaces. ?

Comment: maybe is there a trim function ?

Comment: can u use the trim please?

Comment: it still goes into the `if`

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, I have updated answer you dont need `!`

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` doesnt return true/false. You should check for `.val()length == 0` instead of `!val()`

```
if (($("#RdbDateRange").is(':checked'))
        && (!$.trim($("#CldrFrom").val()).length == 0)
        && (!$.trim($("#CldrTo").val()).lenght == 0)) {}else{}
```

Comment: so what should I do please?

Comment: maybe it is just spaces. I mean whites spaces without actually data

Answer (score 0):

Replace  `!$("#CldrFrom").val()` with    `if($("#CldrFrom").val().trim() !="")`

Comment: it still goes into the `if`

Answer (score 0):

You must compare in the `if` clause

```
 if (($("#RdbDateRange").is(':checked'))
    && (!$("#CldrFrom").val()=="something")
    && (!$("#CldrTo").val()!="")) {}else{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
&& (!$("#CldrTo").val().length)) {
//Text is not empty....code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (($("#RdbDateRange").is(':checked'))
        && ($("#CldrFrom").val() !='')
        && ($("#CldrTo").val() !='')) {}else{}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c74ke/1/)